# SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load() fails with "Cannot find module"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, systemjs

In my angular 6 application I'm trying to dynamically load a module using `SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load()` but it always fails with a "Cannot find module" error.

[This small sample program on GitHub](https://github.com/rhegner/Angular6ModuleLoadTest) reproduces the problem. It is nothing more than a new Angular-CLI generated project with one additional module which I try to load dynamically. It fails with the following error message in the console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "src/app/lazy/lazy.module".

What's going wrong here?

---

**Note**: I was trying to reproduce the problem on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kudvst?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) before. However that was misleading since the error message was slightly different:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'LazyModule' in 'app/lazy/lazy.module'

It turned out (thanks to Cam Plimsoll) that I was just using the wrong path in that example.

Comment: Those look similar same but I believe they are very different errors.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But still I hope knowing what's wrong with the toy example will help me understand why my real application is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Load the module with the path starting from the sourceRoot

```
this.loader.load('src/app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule').then(module=>{     
      //handle the logic of inserting your component
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This indeed fixes my StackBlitz example. But in my real app this doesn't solve the problem (remember that the error message looks slightly different). So I created a new minimal sample program on GitHub which reproduces the problem with the exact same error message as in my real application - please see my updated question.